# ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'keyboard'

Tags: python-3.x, import, terminal, module

I use Linux Mint, previously pip installed keyboard and have a document called "Executer.py". The document contains the following code:

`import keyboard`

In the terminal I ran the following:

`cd Desktop/`

`python3 Executer.py`

Output:

`Traceback (most recent call last):`

`File "/home/rylee/Desktop/Executer.py", line 1, in <module>`

`import keyboard`

`"ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'keyboard"`

Comment: Did you `pip install keyboard` to the same interpreter that you're running the script with? `pip` may refer the Python 2's pip if you have a Python 2 installation on your system.